# jquery datatables scrollx and multiple-select filter css

Tags: css, select, datatables

I use datatables from website : www.datatables.net and multiple-select (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/) filter in my datatables. I wrote this code to do this :

```
this.api().columns().every(function () {

var column = this;


var select = $('<select multiple="multiple" style="width:inherit"><option value=""></option></select>')


.appendTo($(column.header()).empty())


select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');
select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');
select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');
select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');
select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');
select.append('<option value="value1">value1</option>');

select.multipleSelect({
});
});
```

I uploaded picture to : http://postimg.org/image/ys0q3ajxx/
which exactly describes my problem.

Sorry for the link, but I am not able to insert a picture because I got error : "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Everything is fine and works like a charm.

But problem appears when I use 'scrollX' = true option -> It is needed because I have more than 20 columns to display sometimes !

Problem appears that when I click on this "select" -> the list appears but it is covered by "datatables body rows". This problem does not occur when I use "standard select".

I suppose that this problem is connected with "Css styling", but I do not know how to correct this.

When I turn off "scrollX" option, my multiple-select works fine -> List appears "on the top" of the datatables body, but when "scrollX" is turned on -> this list is covered by "datatables body".

Could you help me how to fix it ?

Comment: SO allows you to insert an image into a question so please edit your question to do this instead of linking to it. This way future readers will be able to understand the issue if the link dies

Comment: check `z-index` property of that multiSelect dropdown div, set it to maximum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found this property couple hours ago, but unfortunately it does not work :(